# prevent CoreData from returning cached results

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

I am querying for a Client NSManagedObject via Core Data in my app and displaying the result in a simple details UIView pushed onto my UINavigationsController stack - nothing complex or out of the ordinary.

When I navigate back out of this details page for this Client object I am also checking for updates to my Clients in the background and if there are some I update my data store quietly in a background thread on a different managed object context.  This is working and I see the changes to the data appear in my Core Data store via my SQLite Database Browser so I know the data has been updated.

The problem is when I navigate back to that same Client I will not see the changes unless I completely close my app or select a different Client and then go back to the one I know has changes.  It seems the last Client object fetch request is being cached by my managed object context.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` passing the background `NSManagedObjectContext` as the object and then call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` when the notification fires on your `NSManagedObjectContext` on the main thread.
This is specified in the [Core Data Programming Guide: Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). And dont forget to refresh the data in your view (if it is a table view call `reloadData`)

Comment: worked perfectly, much easier to implement than I thought it was going to be - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an overly simple solution, but are you reloading your data in **viewWillAppear:** ?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```